# How best to transfer posts from one WordPress site to another (without administrator or FTP access)

Tags: wordpress

I produce content for a number of clients, and at the moment, my writers produce content within the client site WordPress backends. I would like to change this so that my writers create posts within my own WordPress install so that they can go through a streamlined collaborative editorial process before the content (once approved) is exported to the client site.

The main stumbling block I am considering is how to get the content from my site to the client's site. Copying and pasting the HTML would be simple enough; the only problem is that the images would still be stored on my site (not on the client's), which isn't something I would like (nor would my clients, presumably).

The obvious solution would be to upload the images to the client site as part of the import process, but that would be fiddly (having to update alt text, caption, width, etc.).

Any better ideas?

Comment: Hi Tom, what about, WordPress import export? Just select the posts by author or date for specific client, get export xml file, then go in client's WP site and import the file under Tools -> Import -> WordPress .. and tick import attachments also, this way all images will also be taken care.

Comment: Hi Mohsin! Exporting wouldn't be an issue, but importing would be, as I don't have administrator access on client sites, and thus don't have access to the Import function.

Comment: Also, import/export functionality doesn't have fine-grained control; e.g. you can only import by a particular author for an entire month. Not much use if they've written five articles in a month and you only want to import one of them.

Comment: I see! I think there are plugins which can enhance export setup to give you more control, however not having admin access on client side is an issue, I think you can overcome this, requesting client?, then it is just matter of choosing some good export plugin..e.g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-exporter/ you can select individual posts (have not used myself.)

Comment: Looks like a good plugin for exporting, but I'm afraid there's no way that clients are going to give me administrator access to their sites!

Comment: I think if you don't have admin access to importing/client site then I am afraid to say you might have only manual option to go.